Emissary ingress | Connecting Lambda to a Kubernetes ClusterIP Service in an EKS cluster in the Same VPC
We are using Emissary Ingress (Ambassador) in our EKS cluster as our API gateway. We have an ALB attached to our Emissary Ingress running natively in our Kubernetes cluster. Now, I want to allow Lambda functions to reach a service within the cluster that is of the ClusterIP type. Both the Lambda and EKS cluster are in the same VPC.
Is there a way to achieve this? Has anyone tried connecting a Lambda to a ClusterIP service in an EKS cluster?
